# Project with Path not found in Project Path

Tags: spring, gradle, dependencies, project

I have 3 projects Projecta, ProjectB, ProjectC.

```
ProjectA
    ProjectB
       ProjectC
```

When I build ProjectB it builds without any problem.But when I try to build ProjectA it fails with following error on console.

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':ProjectB'.
>   Project with path ':ProjectC' could not be found in project ':ProjectB'.

build.gradle - ProjectC

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
repositories{
    jcenter{
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
dependencies {      
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.8.RELEASE'
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.5'
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.5'
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.5'
   compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' 
   runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}
```

settings.gradle - ProjectC

```
rootProject.name = 'ProjectC'
```

build.gradle - ProjectB

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
repositories{
    jcenter{
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
dependencies {    
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile project(':ProjectC')
}
```

settings.gradle - ProjectB

```
include(':ProjectC')
project(':ProjectC').projectDir = new File('../ProjectC')
rootProject.name = 'ProjectB'
```

build.gradle - ProjectA

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
repositories{
    jcenter{
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
dependencies {    
    compile project(':ProjectB')
}
```

settings.gradle - ProjectA

```
include(':ProjectB')
project(':ProjectB').projectDir = new File('../ProjectB/')
rootProject.name = 'ProjectA'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the adding dependency of `projectC` in the `projectB`

```
compile project(':ProjectC')
```

Should be

```
runtime project(':ProjectC')
```

In opposite case it's supposed the projectC already exist on higher levels

UPDATE:

AN alternative could be adding `projectC` in the list of dependencies of `projectA`

Comment: It didn't solved the problem. If this would have been the problem then building ProjectB should have also failed, but building ProjectB builds successfully.

Comment: ProjectB builds successfully but later the projectC dependency is not included so projectA has no access to projectC

Comment: Thanks for help. Adding dependency of ProjectC in ProjectA solved the problem.Please add this to the answer and I'll accept it.